# Test class coverage for apex class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to write a Test class for one of my class, however the coverage is not even changing a bit. Please help

Class-

```
public with sharing class accountTriggerHelperClass {
public static List <Account> sendEmail(List<Account> accs){
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (Account acct : accs) {    
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'account_deletion@apex.salesforce.com'});       
    email.setSubject('' + acct.Name + '');
    System.debug('abc' + acct.Name);
    email.setPlainTextBody('Test' + acct.Name + '');
    emails.add(email);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);    
return accs;
}
}
```

Test class-

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
global class TestAccountTriggerHelperClass{    
public static void sendEmail(){
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   // mail.setTargetObjectId(accountId);        
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}  

private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    Account acc =  new Account();
    acc.Name = 'ACT15';

    insert acc;

    String address = 'abc@gmail.com';
    String subject = 'ACT15';
    String body = 'Test ACT15 ';
    //EmailManager.sendMail(address, subject, body);      
}
}
```

Comment: You need to call your `accountTriggerHelperClass.sendEmail` method from the test.

Comment: And identify the test method to run to the test framework using testMethod or @isTest.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am calling sendEmail method at line 3- "public static void sendEmail(){" and I am using @isTest annotation. I am new to Test classes, is there any other way to call methods in test classes. Please help me with a sample code.

Comment: You are declaring a method at line 3 not calling it. To get it called by the test framework you have to mark it as described in my last comment. Also see my first comment. Google for sample test code and follow the patterns you find.

Comment: Your class doesn't quite make sense to me. Generally speaking, emails are sent to contacts at accounts, not to accounts, but perhaps you have a default email address for each account? Normally, you'd want to create a related contact to insert for the account and send the email to the contact. Also, you don't need `SeeAllData=true` if you're creating your test data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too old to be of any value without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call sendEmail() from your Test Class.
Try this code:

```
@isTest
global class testAccountTriggerHelperClass{
    public static testmethod void emailTest(){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name='test';

        INSERT acc;

        List  lstAccount = new List ();
        lstAccount.add(acc);

       // accountTriggerHelperClass cls = new accountTriggerHelperClass();
        accountTriggerHelperClass.sendEmail(lstAccount);

    }
}
```

Comment: The test class got saved and ran successfully with 100% coverage... Thanks a lot  for your help @Aditya M

Comment: Glad to be of help!